# Code inside "hover" CSS selector stops working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a small and interactive image gallery inside my page and everything besides this problem is working fine: When I mouse over the images they change opacity and size, as expected, however, after I click one of them and enlarge it, nothing happens when I try mousing over them again.

This is what I mean:

[image: example]

Current CSS:

```
#houseImages img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 1em;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 18em;
    height: 15em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.05em;
}

#houseImages img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: 1.0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Current script that is being used when an image is clicked:

```
"use strict";

function defaultSettings(imgElement)
{
    imgElement.style.position = "initial";
    imgElement.style.transform = "scale(1.0)";
    imgElement.style.opacity = "0.7";
}

function clickedSettings(imgElement)
{
    imgElement.style.position = "absolute";
    imgElement.style.transform = "scale(2.6)";
    imgElement.style.left = "40%";
    imgElement.style.top = "30%";
    imgElement.style.opacity = "1.0";
    imgElement.style.zIndex = "99";
}

function imageClicked(imgID)
{
    let img = document.getElementById("img" + imgID);
    let otherImages = document.querySelectorAll("#houseImages img:not(#img" + imgID + ")");
    let div = document.getElementById("houseImages");
    let previousCloseImageButton = document.querySelector("#houseImages button");

    // if another image was already clicked there's some cleanup to do
    if(previousCloseImageButton)
        previousCloseImageButton.remove();

    otherImages.forEach(image => defaultSettings(image));

    clickedSettings(img);

    let closeImageButton = document.createElement('button');
    closeImageButton.setAttribute("id","close");
    closeImageButton.setAttribute("onclick","notClicked(" + imgID + ")");
    closeImageButton.innerHTML = 'X';
    div.append(closeImageButton);
}

function notClicked(imgID)
{
    let img = document.getElementById("img" + imgID);
    let closeImageButton = document.querySelector("#houseImages button");

    defaultSettings(img);

    closeImageButton.remove();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `defaultSettings(img);` in the `notClicked(imgID)` function, you are setting a style property directly on the HTML img objects, as if you have written `<img style="opacity: 0.7">` in HTML. Styles set on an object always have higher priority than those resulting from a stylesheet. In effect, rules defined for `#houseImages img:hover` cannot affect your image.
What you need to do is *unset* a local style property to let the stylesheet work again:

```js
function defaultSettings(imgElement)
{
    imgElement.style.position = "";
    imgElement.style.transform = "";
    imgElement.style.opacity = "";
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know or think about that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just set a class and remove it.

Comment: @epascarello Has also a good idea, definitely leading to better code: instead of changing the `.style` properties, define a CSS class like `.clicked` and add it with `element.classList.add("clicked")`. Later you can remove the class to have the element go back to normal. This way all the style values (e.g. how big the image should get) are defined in CSS rather than in random places of JS code.

Comment: @wgslr If the applied inline style has different definitions from the one's in the sheet, it doesn't suppose to override the ones in the sheet, does it ?

Comment: @AlonAdler Do you mean different attributes? Then yes, setting for example "posiioon" inline does not override "opacity" or "color" set in the stylesheet.